# Метод, который возвращает объект с неизвестным типом, который хранится в переменной

Tags: java, классы, методы, generics

В программировании я довольно молод и неопытен. Потому не удаётся мне реализовать одно дельце.
У меня есть метод, который возвращает объект типа T, который у нас первоначально неизвестен. На деле это будет класс, находящийся в массиве:

```
List<Class> classes
```

Так вот, сам метод будет принимать какой-нибудь объект и индекс, который и будет означать номер класса в массиве classes. Метод должен возвратить объект, переведенный к типу этого самого класса.

```
public <T> T get(Object obj,int int){return (T)obj;}
```

Вот тут и начинаются проблемы: как же сообщить дженерику T, какой у нас должен получится метод? Пробовал так(см. ниже), ругается IDE, мол, нельзя переприсвоить значение классу T

```
public <T> T get(Object obj,int index){
    T=classes.get(index);
    return (T)obj;
}
```

Comment: Видимо не знаю я и работы cast. ~~~obj.cast(classes.index);~~~ Почему-то, когда передаю значения внутрь метода cast, IDE просто требует создать в текущем классе метод cast. И всё...

Comment: `cast` - это медод класса `Class`, т.е. вызывать его нужно так: `classes.get(i).cast(obj)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы хотите сделать делается так:

```
public <T> T cast(Object obj, int i){
    Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>)classes.get(i);
    return clazz.cast(obj);
}
```

Обычно вообще принято передавать сам класс в качестве параметра, т.е. ваш код может выглядеть ещё как-то так, но для этого в принципе и метод может быть лишним:

```
someMethod() {
    //...
    castObject(myObject, classes.get(i));
    //...
}

public <T> T castObject(Object obj, Class<T> clazz){
    return clazz.cast(obj);
}
```

Но учтите: то, что вы хотите сделать это прямой путь выстрелить в ногу и получить `ClassCastException`, поэтому прежде чем это делать, нужно понимать зачем вам это и нельзя ли как-то заменить эту задачу другой, менее опасной.